# How to add new item in recyclerview without refreshing other item

Tags: android, firebase, chat, android-recyclerview

I'm developing chat application. Every thing works fine  but when data is added or removed from then from the chat then how to update that item without disturbing other just like Facebook and Whatsapp.
[image]

This is my database.

[image]

i know about `mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);` but how we do for nested recyclerview ?

Comment: data comes from firebase ?

Comment: yes  data  coming from `firebase `.

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: this is single `recyclerview`  i have nested.

Answer (score 1):

To update a particular row, you can use following

```
mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
```

Comment: i know this .how you this for nested `recyvlerview` and when data update by another user ?

Comment: in above example, for what purpose are you using nested recyclerview?
cause i can c only one recycler view

Comment: Date is main recyclerview and messages are child recyclerview .

Comment: What is the behaviour of your Views now? What happens every time you type a message? As a general comment: Each RV needs its adapter and its ViewHolder. A parent Adapter (in your case dates) organizes the children and calls the relevant child adapter( typed messages)

Comment: @Pointyhat   Currently whenever new message is added to the list or message removed from list whole list refresh and this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**use FirebaseUI for Realtime Database**

The FirebaseRecyclerAdapter binds a Query to a RecyclerView. When data is added, removed, or changed these updates are automatically applied to your UI in real time.

see this link [Firebase UI for realtime database](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md)

you won't regret with

Comment: Ok but we use for nested recyclerview .Bcoz i have show messages by the dates just like whatsapp and many more application. Let show you my database stucture.